# Why isn't my table showing any border?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I'm using a master page and I have a table that I want to show a border around so that it shows around each cell in the table. Here's the code I'm trying to put a border around:

```
<table class="mainTable" style="border-color:#DDDDDD;">
    <tr>
        <td class="masterBannerTop" colspan="6" >
            <a href="Default.aspx"><img style="border: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" alt="Travel Joan's Blog Banner" src="Website%20Photos/HeadBanner.jpg" /></a>
        </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="masterBannerNav"><a href="Default.aspx">HOME</a></td>
    <td class="masterBannerNav"><a href="About.aspx">ABOUT ME</a></td>
    <td>
```

... And it goes on from there. Here's the CSS:

```
.mainTable
    {
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        border-spacing: 30px;
        border-color:#999999;
    }
```

No matter what color I put in, it doesn't work in any of the browsers. I mean, there's only a couple places where I can put the color. Even if i try to use just CSS or in-line style elements, it still doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: You Shouldn't be using tables unless if it is for an Html email. But if you must, trying adding a border thickness to your table and make it a display block to see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting

```
border:1px solid #999999;
```

in your css instead of fiddling around with table attributes! Try to avoid using these attributes because it makes changing the style of your site more difficult and the code more verbose for people that have to maintain it. Good luck and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as soon as I can. Generally speaking, what I was missing was setting the width of my border. It seems like they would automatically create a border when you set any border attribute.

Comment: Yep :) It depends on the browser as well!

Answer (score 1):

style="border: 1px solid black"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps also make sure you set border-width: 1px or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
<table border="1"> ... </table>
```

to get borders around your table and between cells.

Do

```
<table style="border:'1px solid #DDDDDD'"> ... </table>
```

or

```
.mainTable {
    border:'1px solid #DDDDDD';
    ...
}
```

or

```
.mainTable {
    border-size:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    ...
}
```

to get borders around your table.